# Generics in TypeScript Vue Component

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, typescript-generics

I am trying to supply generic type into vue component, but don't know how to supply that from the caller.

For example, for the component below

```
export default class Toggle<T> extends Vue {
    @Prop({ default: {} })    private payload!: T;
    @Prop(Function)           private handleCallback!: (payload: T) => Promise<any>;
}
```

how would I supply type for `T`when it is called as below?

`<toggle :payload="{propOfT: 'value of T'}" :handleCallback='someCallbackFn'/>`

Comment: I've done this differently in the past. Instead of using Toggle<T> I would just call it Toggle. Your prop would require an interface instead of T. That should give you a similar solution without generics. I don't think Vue does very well with generics for components...

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can use

```
extend<Data, Methods, Computed, Props>(options?: ThisTypedComponentOptionsWithRecordProps<V, Data, Methods, Computed, Props>): ExtendedVue<V, Data, Methods, Computed, Props>;



interface Data {
  dataProp: boolean
}

interface Methods {
  methodOne: (name: Type) => Promise<void>
}

interface Props {
  items: Item[]
}

export default Vue.extend<Data, Methods, {}, Props>({ ...
```